# Egit error connecting to remote repo

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

Im having some difficulties connecting my project in eclipse with my remote repo with EGit.
I have already created a local git repo and now I want to connect it to github, but when I add the URI and use a https protocol I get:

```
"Internal error; consult Eclipse error log."
```

And I get this message in the Eclipse error log:

```
Error validating org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.components.RepositorySelectionPage
```

How can I fix this?

What I do is that I go to remotes, right click it and select "Create remote...".
I then change the URI, and I add "https://github.com/Lumberfella/angularApp.git" to the URI input box, and the Host and Repository path auto fills themselves to:

```
Host: github.com
Repository path: /Lumberfella/angularApp.git
```

and In the connection section I have https as the Protocol.

When I do this, its already giving me an error at the top of the "Select URI" window saying: "internal error; consult Eclipse error log." which is what I posted above.

Im using EGit version 3.3.1

Comment: Please, add some more info to start with: what EGit version are you using; what repository do you try to connect to; how did you fill out the wizard. It is most likely an EGit bug, but it could have been triggered by an incorrectly filled Repository selection form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out you repository, and it seemed that repository is empty. I am not entirely sure about this answer, but I believe, you cannot use the read-only http urls on empty repositories (e.g. they have no branches to pull).

This theory is further supported by the exception trace I have found in the Error log view:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: test
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:136)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.FetchOperation.run(FetchOperation.java:127)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:100)
... 64 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: test: not found.
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportLocal$1.open(TransportLocal.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportBundleFile$1.open(TransportBundleFile.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:556)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:287)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:120)
... 66 more
```

Basically, the trace says, it cannot get contents from the remote repository.

Comment: oh ok, then Is it possible to use ssh?

Comment: I have now tried doing it with a ssh URI, and It says everything is working except I get an Authentification fail.

Comment: For SSH URIs (at least in case of Github) you have to use the git user (instead of your own), and rely on public key based authentication. See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys for details.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make it work by adding a remote repository by adding the https or ssh inside eclipse in remotes.

But since I was able to make a working local repository, I figured all I needed to do was download the Git Shell and add a new remote repository that way.

For some reason this totally worked and it also automaticly connected the remote repository to eclipse, so Im now able to push directly from eclipse to both the local and the remote repository (or which ever I would like to).